# yeoman and grunt serve not rendering images

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I have a project generated with [yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) with this command :

```
yo angular
```

I am having this peace of code

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, flatmate) in flatmates">
   {{flatmate.name}} <img ng-src="{{flatmate.staticPath}}" >
 </div>
```

not rendering the images.

I am sure of the path (because when I put a wrong path I have 404 error).

My images are under app/images ( seems fine)

There is no error, just images are not displayed.
any idea ?

Comment: can you please past the error?

Comment: There is no error, just images are not displayed.

Comment: in console, if an image is not visualized you should get a 404 error

Comment: I suppose that you have not configured your server in order to serve static files, so, could you  try to paste in your browser the full generated path and have a look if it works?

Comment: i get redirected if i paste the url in my browser.

Comment: how can i serve static files with angular ??